# running powershell inside VS Code from docker on WSL2

Tags: docker, powershell, visual-studio-code, wsl-2

I am trying to use the "remote container"-functionality of VS Code, but parts of the build-script needs to run as a windows-process.

So the setup gets kind of complicated:

windows 10 -> WSL2 -> docker -> VS Code (server) -> bash -> powershell

Without docker, this works great (windows running WSL2 starting a windows-executable), through some kind of magic. Inside docker, some of the magic is not present...

I figured out that I need to run docker in privileged mode to be able to mount `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc` where I find the `WSLInterop`-file, but this is apparently not enough.

What other magic do I need in order to get WSL2 to execute a windows process?

```
root@ea31e9627f7a:/# mount -t binfmt_misc binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/
root@ea31e9627f7a:/# cat /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/WSLInterop 
enabled
interpreter /tools/init
flags: F
offset 0
magic 4d5a
root@ea31e9627f7a:/# powershell.exe
root@ea31e9627f7a:/# which powershell.exe
/opt/windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0//powershell.exe
root@ea31e9627f7a:/#
```

The reference to `interpreter /tools/init` is some kind of magic I havent figured out. In WSL2 I have:

```
$ mount | grep /init
tools on /init type 9p (ro,relatime,dirsync,aname=tools;fmask=022,loose,access=client,trans=fd,rfd=6,wfd=6)
```

But I have not been able to figure out how to replicate this inside docker (or if it will matter)

My development environment is here: https://github.com/rolfrander/smarthome

(I guess one could argue that this setup is just too complicated, but the experience of developing inside a docker container is really nice)

Comment: *"I guess one could argue that this setup is just too complicated."*  Sure, but does it really *need* to be that complicated in order to reproduce your core issue?  In other words, can you get a more [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the sake of simplifying the question and isolating the issue?  I'm *thinking* (but still working on grok'ing the question) that your core question is (for starters) how to run `powershell.exe` inside an Ubuntu docker container using WSL interop?  We really don't need to bring VSCode into the equation *just yet*, do we?

Comment: Second question (that someone will ask if I don't).  Is your end goal `powershell.exe`, or is that just your test case before you run some other Windows executable?  If PowerShell is the end-goal, does it have to be Windows PowerShell?  Or would installing Linux PowerShell in the container be a viable option?  Guessing it won't, but have to ask.

Comment: Alternatively, and I haven't tried this myself, is it possible that a [Windows docker container](https://dockerlabs.collabnix.com/intermediate/docker-desktop-for-windows/lab02-switching-to-windows-container.html) might work instead of using Ubuntu as the container base?

Comment: Good questions. I was able to reproduce the problem without VSCode, running an Alpine container. The end goal is not powershell, it is uploading a Sming firmware to and ESP8266 development board through and USB-to-Serial-bridge. WSL does not have access to windows COM-ports, so the Sming build-system calls the upload-program through powershell. The possible workarounds here are running the Sming-build in cygwin instead of WSL, or moving the firmware out of the docker-container and uploading manually. However, it would be nice to get the integrated experience working.

Comment: In reproducing the issue with Alpine and using `strace`, I have been able to narrow the issue down to sockets in `/run/WSL`. Starting docker from within Linux/WSL I am able to mount this directory and call back to windows, so I am getting somewhere. However, starting the docker container from VSCode seems to just have access to windows-directories. (I can't even begin to explain how any of this works, docker, within a virtual linux, within windows, but in a way that the linux is transparent. Pure magic!)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I think I figured this out. In WSL `/init` acts as a bridge between linux and windows. `$WSL_INTEROP` points to a socket in `/run/WSL` for communicating with init. Privileged mode is not needed.

compare

```
$ docker run --rm -i -t --volume /mnt/c/Windows/:/opt/windows alpine sh
/ # /opt/windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe -c '$PSVersionTable'
/ #
```

with

```
$ docker run --rm -i -t --volume /mnt/c/Windows/:/opt/windows --volume /run/WSL:/run/WSL --env WSL_INTEROP=$WSL_INTEROP alpine sh
/ # /opt/windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe -c '$PSVersionTable'

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.906
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.906
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1


/ #
```

(Running windows commands directly from the docker command line doesn't work, not sure why)

Don't do this unless you understand the implications. This basically breaks a hole in the container enabling processes inside the container to speak directly with the windows host.

Also note that the current directory of the process starting is set to the windows equivalent of the current linux directory, and if the command is started from some directory which isn't available (or if WSL can't determine the correct windows directory), the command will fail with "Invalid argument".

Now, for the VSCode part, it seems I need to first start VSCode remote in WSL, then start the remote container from there, this enables docker mounts to refer to linux directories and not windows directories. I've had succes with a `devcontainer.json` like this:

```
{
    "build": {"dockerfile": "Dockerfile"},
    "extensions": ["ms-vscode.cpptools"],
    "mounts": [
        "source=/mnt/c/Windows,target=/opt/windows,type=bind,ro=true",
        "source=/run/WSL/,target=/run/WSL,type=bind,ro=true"
    ],
    "remoteEnv": {
        "PATH": "${containerEnv:PATH}:/opt/windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/"
    }
}
```

Regarding WSL_INTEROP, see [this](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5065) discussion.

Comment: *"Now, for the VSCode part, it seems I need to first start VSCode remote in WSL*"  Cool - That makes sense.  And good find on the Interop discussion n Github.  I think that explains why I sometimes have (hopefully *had*) a broken pipe when running wrapping `pwsh.exe` inside `tmux` inside an Alpine WSL instance.